# Google App Engine does not recognized @Named parameter

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine%22Google%20Plugin%20for%20Eclipse%22), and I am writing an App Engine app as a Dynamic Web Module in Eclipse WTP.

I have defined the following Java class to serve as a Cloud Endpoint API:

```
package mypackage;

import static mypackage.OfyService.ofy;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import mypackage.models.ProbeEntry;
import mypackage.models.ProbeSet;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

@Api(name = "analysisEndpoint", 
    version = "v1", 
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                                ownerDomain = "myorg", 
                                ownerName = "myorg", 
                                packagePath = "analysis")
        )
public class AnalysisEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AnalysisEndpoint.class.getName());

    @ApiMethod(name = "getMyProbeEntries", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
    public ProbeSet getMyProbeEntries(@Named("amount") int amount) {
        ObjectifyService.begin();

        List<ProbeEntry> probeList = ofy().load().type(ProbeEntry.class).limit(amount).list();

        return new ProbeSet(probeList);
    }
}
```

I attempt to deploy to the Google App Engine by right-clicking the project -> Google App Engine WTP -> Deploy Project to Remote Server. I see in my console that the project is compiling and uploading, but eventually errors out with:

```
99% Endpoints configuration not updated.  The app returned an error when the Google Cloud Endpoints server attempted to communicate with it.
```

The error log on the app engine shows the following:

```
18:31:58.119
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.MissingParameterNameException: analysisEndpoint.myorg.analysis.AnalysisEndpoint.getMyProbeEntries parameter (type int): Missing parameter name. Parameter type (int) is not an entity type and thus should be annotated with @Named.
        at     
com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.ApiConfigValidator.validateApiParameter(ApiConfigValidator.java:214)
        ...
```

As can be seen in the code, I do have `@Named("amount")` before the offending parameter. What is going wrong here? Side note: If I simply remove the `amount` parameter, the project deploys to App Engine without a problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any solution ? Im having the same problem